# How do I make a web form already have inputs? on external site

Tags: html, css

So basically what I want is to set up an image link http://www.giftrocket.com/send-a-gift-card

What I want is for the Recipient name: field to already have the name written and recipient email too. Or to know if its even possible since I do not own giftrocket. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't.  Unless you have access to the page that is handling the form processing, you have no control over it.  In other words, you can't make someone else's form go to YOUR page for processing.

Think of the security nightmare that would create if it were possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it's not possible to fill in the fields with pure javascript/html due to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Is it possible with anything other than JavaScript? OP didn't mention JavaScript or any method to do it with.

Comment: @putvande I don't know of any ways to do so, but I'm not certain enough to say there aren't any. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful :/